# Get information of employee from Employee ID in Sharepoint Framework(SPFX) using REST API

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I am using Sharepoint Framework(SPFX) and using Typescript for calling REST APIs. I want to get information of other employees from Office 365 or Active Directory using their Email ID or Employee ID.

How can I do this with REST API in Sharepoint Framework(SPFX)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the properties you would like to access, you could pull this from the [SharePoint Search REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)

Another option is using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0). You can play with that using the cool [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and see what the different calls will provide you with. 
For example, this one will give you details about a specific user account:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/first.last@email.com
```

This one will require some extra steps to request permissions to access the API itself, read about that [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial#configure-the-api-permissions-requests)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this method will help. It retrieves a list with expanded Userinformation. You need to extend a Person/Group Field (like Created by) when retrieving list items, then you can get user ID, Mail, Department and so on.

```
import { sp, Web, List} from "@pnp/sp";

public getItemsExpandedUser(listTitle: string, selection: string[], expandField: string): Promise<any> {
if (this.createOnFail) {
  return this.ensureList().then((list: List): Promise<any> => {
    return this.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.select(...selection).expand(expandField).getAll().then(result => {
      return result;
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      console.error(error);
      return error;
    });
  });
} else {
  return this.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.select(...selection).expand(expandField).getAll().then(result => {
    return result;
  }).catch((error: any) => {
    console.error(error);
    return error;
  });
}
```

}

An example call could be like this (in Order to get more information of a Person/Group field called 'Employee'):

```
[...] this.getItemsExpandedUser(**YOUR LISTNAME**, ['Id', 'Title', 'Employee', 'Employee/Id', 'Employee/Title', 'Employee/EMail'], 'Employee/Id').then(result => { DO SOMETHING });
```

Comment: Hello, I dont want to get it from list. I want to get it from Office 365.

Comment: oh sorry my fault

Answer (score 0):

ok then. I hope this one will do it ;-)

This method gets all siteUsers:

```
  //get all users with access to the sitecollection
  get fetchSiteUsers(): Promise<IPersona[]> {
    return this.getWeb().siteUsers.get().then(spUsers => {
      console.log(spUsers);
      return spUsers;
    });
  }
```

alternatively you can retriev a single User by using

```
this.getWeb().getUserById(*id*)
```

or for the active logged in user

```
this.getWeb().currentUser.get()
```

if this all is not what you are looking for I'm sorry for taking your time ;-)